# Free Particle moving

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

My class finished the free particle dispersion derivation. Our professor asked us to, as an exercise, modify the derivation to fit a moving particle with a constant velocity. I think I managed it with a slight modification to the original derivation he gave us.

1. Obviously, if the velocity is time dependent, the same derivation does not work at all. For a changing velocity, there must be a force, so there must be a potential term in the se and so the energy eigenfunctions will be completely different. But where in my derivation would I assume that $p$ does not depend on time?
2. What does the Heisenberg uncertainty principle do here? Does it relate the standard deviation of the gaussian with the momentum of the particle? If yes, then how do we handle the zero momentum for the stationary free particle?

Comment: Can you show the derivation you did and are asked to do? Not sure what exactly is being asked.

Comment: @marcus It is a lot of latex to type and I'm not good enough to write that and this site doesn't allow picture, but I searched on Google "quantum mechanics free particle constant velocity", there is an extracted chapter from a book interactive quantum mechanics on the Springer website, I did something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will be difficult for people to help you if they have no idea what you’re referring to. I would recommend learning LaTeX as it’s incredibly useful and, once you get used to it, not that hard to just type on the fly (much easier than a programming language).

Comment: I know a little latex. I just can't do it fast enough to write all of that math. I am trying to get fast but it takes time. I did a derivation very similar to the preview at https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-21653-9_2 but I have different variable names.

Comment: Possibly easier to discuss these questions with your professor or with classmates?